# mystring.replaceAll("},{", "}&{"); fails with PatternSyntaxException

Tags: java, regex, string

`mystring.replaceAll("},{", "}&{");` fails with `PatternSyntaxException`

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1
```

Comment: use this `("\\},\\{", "}&{")`